# How to share socks proxied internet with OpenWrt

Tags: linux, networking, router, ssh, openwrt

I have a router in which installed OpenWrt 22.03.3 and I do `ssh root@192.168.1.1` into it. Then I run these two commands:

```
ssh -fnD 1010 root@my_public_server -pPort
```

Now I can have a `socks` proxy from it, so I do this:

```
export all_proxy=socks5h://localhost:1010
```

Now when I run this command in the openwrt, I see my IP has changed to `my_public_server`:

```
curl api.ipify.org
my_public_server
```

I want to run this proxy in my openwrt's shell permanently and then share this socks proxied internet with other clients connecting to the router device.

At this moment when I connect my mobile to the router, my IP does not change to `my_public_server`'s IP. Instead I see my home ADSL's IP.

For some reasons, I only can do SSH Tunneling and I cannot do other ways like OpenVPN.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You might have to set up some automatic proxy configuration for your local network, pointing to your SOCKS proxy at your router's address. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol

Comment: @Bodo thanks, but I didn't find a way to do that. Do you please help me more?

Comment: Please be more specific about *"I didn't find a way to do that"*. What specifically don't you unerstand in the Wikipedia article? Or what specifically are you having problems with? Since there is no answer yet, you could add the details to your question. Otherwise I would suggest to write a new specific question.

Comment: @Bodo I googled how to run a wpad on linux and things like this, but some sites say a url like `http://wpad/wpad.dat`. I did not understand where the `wpad.dat` should be and how to create it? Also I don't want clients enter any proxy on their devices. I want to do all things in the router (openwrt).

Comment: **Please [edit] your question** to add requested information or clarification or to add more specific questions or requirements. Don't use comments for this purpose. Did you read the [Requirements section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol#Requirements)? One requirement is a (minimal) web server that provides the configuration file under the specified URL. A separate article, which is linked from there, describes the contents of the file with a few examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config